# Cannot compile any software

Tags: compiling, python3

I have Linux Mint 17. I wanted to compile python 3.4.2 from source. During the ./configure command, everything went well until an error came out.

```
configure: creating ./config.status
./config.status: line 476: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./config.status: line 476: `    *\'*) ac_optarg=`$as_echo "$ac_optarg" | sed "s/'/'\\\\\\\\''/g"` ;;'
```

This was not the first time I have had this problem. This problem happens when I compile any software from source.
**EDIT:** I am adding the output of the command     cat -n config.status | sed '463,505!d'

```
case $ac_option in
# Handling of the options.
-recheck | --recheck | --rechec | --reche | --rech | --rec | --re | --r)
ac_cs_recheck=: ;;
--version | --versio | --versi | --vers | --ver | --ve | --v | -V )
$as_echo "$ac_cs_version"; exit ;;
--config | --confi | --conf | --con | --co | --c )
$as_echo "$ac_cs_config"; exit ;;
--debug | --debu | --deb | --de | --d | -d )
debug=: ;;
--file | --fil | --fi | --f )
$ac_shift
case $ac_optarg in
*\'*) ac_optarg=`$as_echo "$ac_optarg" | sed "s/'/'\\\\\\\\''/g"` ;;
'') as_fn_error $? "missing file argument" ;;
esac
as_fn_append CONFIG_FILES " '$ac_optarg'"
ac_need_defaults=false;;
--header | --heade | --head | --hea )
$ac_shift
case $ac_optarg in
*\'*) ac_optarg=`$as_echo "$ac_optarg" | sed "s/'/'\\\\\\\\''/g"` ;;
esac
as_fn_append CONFIG_HEADERS " '$ac_optarg'"
ac_need_defaults=false;;
--he | --h)
# Conflict between --help and --header
as_fn_error $? "ambiguous option: \`$1'
Try \`$0 --help' for more information.";;
--help | --hel | -h )
$as_echo "$ac_cs_usage"; exit ;;
-q | -quiet | --quiet | --quie | --qui | --qu | --q \
| -silent | --silent | --silen | --sile | --sil | --si | --s)
ac_cs_silent=: ;;

# This is an error.
-*) as_fn_error $? "unrecognized option: \`$1'
Try \`$0 --help' for more information." ;;

*) as_fn_append ac_config_targets " $1"
ac_need_defaults=false ;;

esac
```

Comment: Do you get the exact same syntax error for any software? or is it different each time? Is /bin/sh a symlink to dash on your system, or to some other shell?

Comment: I get the same error each time. /bin/sh is a symlink to dash.

Comment: That's strange - the line in question seems to be a perfectly normal part of a standard autoconf case statement. Do you get the same error if you run `./config.status` directly?

Comment: Yes steeldriver. I get that error even if I run ./config.status directly.

Comment: I'm pretty much stumped, the only thing I can suggest is that you edit your post to include some context around the error e.g. the output of `cat -n config.status | sed '463,505!d'`

Comment: OK well the line numbering and formatting seem to have got lost, however I did a `diff -w` between your output and [mine](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9689756/) generated on Ubuntu 12.04 and could not detect any differences. I can only think that there is something non-standard about your shell environment.

Comment: This error doesn't come when compiling libraries such as zlib and sdl.

Comment: I use Linux Mint 17 which is a deriative of Ubuntu 14.04, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you don't use the standard Debian Based package manager for Mint?  Compiling your own isn't recommended.

This kind of things mostly happens because:

1. You have some missing dependencies. which would show up as
   errors, during the './configure' phase.
2. You may have old compiler, or a compiler that doesn't meet the requirements for the package you are compiling. If that is the case you should update your compiler most likely `gcc` to recent versions.  I urge you to use the Debian based package manager to update `gcc` if possible.

Also, you should regularly update your system using the Package Manager.  In situations where you must compile and install something yourself, issue a `./configure` and `make` as a normal user and only use `make install` with root privileges, (i.e `sudo make install`) in the source directory.

Comment: I don't think I miss any dependency. There are no errors about missing dependency. The error says that the config.status that it generated has an error in it. I have the latest verion of gcc and g++. Python 3.4.2 isn't available in the repositories, only Python 3.4.0 is available.